# Wamp SSL :- redirect http to https

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, httpd.conf, apache2.4

I have configured ssl on the port 8090. My httpd_conf file is following

```
    ServerSignature On
    ServerTokens Full

    #
    # ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
    # configuration, error, and log files are kept.
    #
    # Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.  If you point
    # ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to specify a local disk on the
    # Mutex directive, if file-based mutexes are used.  If you wish to share the
    # same ServerRoot for multiple httpd daemons, you will need to change at
    # least PidFile.
    #
    ServerRoot "G:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9"

    Define APACHE24 Apache2.4

    #
    # Mutex: Allows you to set the mutex mechanism and mutex file directory
    # for individual mutexes, or change the global defaults
    #
    # Uncomment and change the directory if mutexes are file-based and the default
    # mutex file directory is not on a local disk or is not appropriate for some
    # other reason.
    #
    # Mutex default:logs

    #
    # Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
    # ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
    # directive.
    #
    # Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
    # prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
    #
    #Listen 12.34.56.78:80

    Listen x.x.x.x:8090



    Listen [::0]:80

    #
    # Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
    #
    # To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
    # have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
    # directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
    # Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
    # to be loaded here.
    #
    # Example:
    # LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
    #
    LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
    LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
    LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
    LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
    LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
    LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
    #LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
    #LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
    LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
    #LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
    #LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
    LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
    #LoadModule authn_socache_module modules/mod_authn_socache.so
    #LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
    LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
    #LoadModule authz_dbd_module modules/mod_authz_dbd.so
    #LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
    LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
    LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
    #LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
    LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
    LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
    #LoadModule buffer_module modules/mod_buffer.so
    LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
    LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
    #LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
    LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
    #LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
    #LoadModule data_module modules/mod_data.so
    #LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
    #LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
    #LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
    #LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
    LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
    LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
    #LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
    LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
    #LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
    #LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
    LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
    #LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
    #LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
    #LoadModule heartbeat_module modules/mod_heartbeat.so
    #LoadModule heartmonitor_module modules/mod_heartmonitor.so
    #LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
    #LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
    LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
    #LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
    LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
    #LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
    #LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
    #LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
    #LoadModule lbmethod_heartbeat_module modules/mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.so
    #LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
    #LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
    LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
    #LoadModule log_debug_module modules/mod_log_debug.so
    #LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
    #LoadModule lua_module modules/mod_lua.so
    LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
    #LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
    LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
    #LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
    #LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
    #LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
    #LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
    #LoadModule proxy_express_module modules/mod_proxy_express.so
    #LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
    #LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
    #LoadModule proxy_html_module modules/mod_proxy_html.so
    #LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
    #LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
    #LoadModule ratelimit_module modules/mod_ratelimit.so
    #LoadModule reflector_module modules/mod_reflector.so
    #LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so
    LoadModule request_module modules/mod_request.so
    #LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
    LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
    #LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so
    #LoadModule session_module modules/mod_session.so
    #LoadModule session_cookie_module modules/mod_session_cookie.so
    #LoadModule session_crypto_module modules/mod_session_crypto.so
    #LoadModule session_dbd_module modules/mod_session_dbd.so
    LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
    #LoadModule slotmem_plain_module modules/mod_slotmem_plain.so
    #LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
    #LoadModule socache_dbm_module modules/mod_socache_dbm.so
    #LoadModule socache_memcache_module modules/mod_socache_memcache.so
    LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
    #LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
    LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
    #LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
    #LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
    #LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
    #LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
    #LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
    #LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
    LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
    #LoadModule watchdog_module modules/mod_watchdog.so
    #LoadModule xml2enc_module modules/mod_xml2enc.so

    LoadModule php5_module "G:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/php5apache2_4.dll"
    #PHPIniDir G:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12

    <IfModule unixd_module>
    #
    # If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
    # httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
    #
    # User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
    # It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
    # running httpd, as with most system services.
    #
    User daemon
    Group daemon

    </IfModule>


    ServerAdmin admin@example.com

    #
    # ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
    # This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
    # it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
    #
    # If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
    #
    ServerName 192.168.1.90:8090

    HostnameLookups off

    #
    # DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
    # documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
    # symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
    #
    DocumentRoot "G:/wamp/www/"

    #
    # Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
    # to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
    # directory (and its subdirectories). 
    #
    # First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of 
    # features.  
    #
    <Directory />
        AllowOverride none
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    #
    # Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
    # particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
    # you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
    # below.
    #

    <Directory "G:/wamp/www/">
        #
        # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
        # or any combination of:
        #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
        #
        # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
        # doesn't give it to you.
        #
        # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
        # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
        # for more information.
        #
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

        #
        # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
        # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
        #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
        #
        #AllowOverride all
        AllowOverride none
        Allow from All
        #
        # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
        #

        #   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    #
    # DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
    # is requested.
    #
    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
    # viewed by Web clients. 
    #
    <Files ".ht*">
        Require all granted
    </Files>

    #
    # ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
    # If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
    # logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
    # container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
    #
    #ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    ErrorLog "G:/wamp/logs/apache_error.log"

    #
    # LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    #
    LogLevel warn

    <IfModule log_config_module>
        #
        # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
        # a CustomLog directive (see below).
        #
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

        <IfModule logio_module>
          # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
          LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
        </IfModule>

        #
        # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
        # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
        # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
        # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
        # logged therein and *not* in this file.
        #
        CustomLog "G:/wamp/logs/access.log" common

        #
        # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
        # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
        #
        #CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule alias_module>
        #
        # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 
        # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client 
        # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
        # Example:
        # Redirect permanent /foo http://www.example.com/bar

        #
        # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
        # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
        # Example:
        # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
        #
        # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
        # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
        # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
        # the filesystem path.

        #
        # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
        # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
        # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
        # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
        # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
        # directives as to Alias.
        #
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "G:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/cgi-bin/"

    </IfModule>

    <IfModule cgid_module>
        #
        # ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
        # socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
        #
        #Scriptsock cgisock
    </IfModule>

    #
    # "G:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
    # CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
    #
    <Directory "G:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mime_module>
        #
        # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
        # filename extension to MIME-type.
        #
        TypesConfig conf/mime.types

        #
        # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
        # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
        #
        #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
        #
        # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
        # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
        #
        AddEncoding x-compress .Z
        AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
        #
        # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
        # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
        #
        AddType application/x-compress .Z
        AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3

        #
        # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
        # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
        # or added with the Action directive (see below)
        #
        # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
        # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
        #
        #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

        # For type maps (negotiated resources):
        #AddHandler type-map var

        #
        # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
        #
        # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
        # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
        #
        #AddType text/html .shtml
        #AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
    # contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
    # directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
    #
    #MIMEMagicFile conf/magic

    #
    # Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
    # 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
    #
    # Some examples:
    #ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
    #ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
    #ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
    #ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
    #

    #
    # MaxRanges: Maximum number of Ranges in a request before
    # returning the entire resource, or one of the special
    # values 'default', 'none' or 'unlimited'.
    # Default setting is to accept 200 Ranges.
    #MaxRanges unlimited

    #
    # EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it, 
    # memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall may be used to deliver
    # files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
    # be turned off when serving from networked-mounted 
    # filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
    # broken on your system.
    # Defaults: EnableMMAP On, EnableSendfile Off
    #
    #EnableMMAP off
    EnableSendfile off

    # AcceptFilter: On Windows, none uses accept() rather than AcceptEx() and
    # will not recycle sockets between connections. This is useful for network
    # adapters with broken driver support, as well as some virtual network
    # providers such as vpn drivers, or spam, virus or spyware filters.
    AcceptFilter http none
    AcceptFilter https none

    # Supplemental configuration
    #
    # The configuration files in the conf/extra/ directory can be 
    # included to add extra features or to modify the default configuration of 
    # the server, or you may simply copy their contents here and change as 
    # necessary.

    # Server-pool management (MPM specific)
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

    # Multi-language error messages
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf

    # Fancy directory listings
    Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

    # Language settings
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf

    # User home directories
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

    # Real-time info on requests and configuration
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-info.conf

    # Virtual hosts
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

    # Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-manual.conf

    # Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf

    # Various default settings
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf

    # Configure mod_proxy_html to understand HTML4/XHTML1
    <IfModule proxy_html_module>
    Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
    </IfModule>

    # Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
    Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
    #
    # Note: The following must must be present to support
    #       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
    #       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
    #
    <IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
    </IfModule>
    #
    # uncomment out the below to deal with user agents that deliberately
    # violate open standards by misusing DNT (DNT *must* be a specific
    # end-user choice)
    #
    #<IfModule setenvif_module>
    #BrowserMatch "MSIE 10.0;" bad_DNT
    #</IfModule>
    #<IfModule headers_module>
    #RequestHeader unset DNT env=bad_DNT
    #</IfModule>


    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot "g:/wamp/www"
    </VirtualHost>

    #IncludeOptional "G:/wamp/vhosts/*"
    Include "G:/wamp/alias/*"
```

httpd_ssl.conf is following

```
#
        # This is the Apache server configuration file providing SSL support.
        # It contains the configuration directives to instruct the server how to
        # serve pages over an https connection. For detailed information about these 
        # directives see <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html>
        # 
        # Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
        # what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
        # consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
        #
        # Required modules: mod_log_config, mod_setenvif, mod_ssl,
        #          socache_shmcb_module (for default value of SSLSessionCache)

        #
        # Pseudo Random Number Generator (PRNG):
        # Configure one or more sources to seed the PRNG of the SSL library.
        # The seed data should be of good random quality.
        # WARNING! On some platforms /dev/random blocks if not enough entropy
        # is available. This means you then cannot use the /dev/random device
        # because it would lead to very long connection times (as long as
        # it requires to make more entropy available). But usually those
        # platforms additionally provide a /dev/urandom device which doesn't
        # block. So, if available, use this one instead. Read the mod_ssl User
        # Manual for more details.
        #
        #SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/random  512
        #SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom 512
        #SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/random  512
        #SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/urandom 512


        #
        # When we also provide SSL we have to listen to the 
        # standard HTTP port (see above) and to the HTTPS port
        #
        Listen 8090

        ##
        ##  SSL Global Context
        ##
        ##  All SSL configuration in this context applies both to
        ##  the main server and all SSL-enabled virtual hosts.
        ##

        #   SSL Cipher Suite:
        #   List the ciphers that the client is permitted to negotiate.
        #   See the mod_ssl documentation for a complete list.
        SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5

        #   Speed-optimized SSL Cipher configuration:
        #   If speed is your main concern (on busy HTTPS servers e.g.),
        #   you might want to force clients to specific, performance
        #   optimized ciphers. In this case, prepend those ciphers
        #   to the SSLCipherSuite list, and enable SSLHonorCipherOrder.
        #   Caveat: by giving precedence to RC4-SHA and AES128-SHA
        #   (as in the example below), most connections will no longer
        #   have perfect forward secrecy - if the server's key is
        #   compromised, captures of past or future traffic must be
        #   considered compromised, too.
        #SSLCipherSuite RC4-SHA:AES128-SHA:HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
        #SSLHonorCipherOrder on 

        #   Pass Phrase Dialog:
        #   Configure the pass phrase gathering process.
        #   The filtering dialog program (`builtin' is an internal
        #   terminal dialog) has to provide the pass phrase on stdout.
        SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

        #   Inter-Process Session Cache:
        #   Configure the SSL Session Cache: First the mechanism 
        #   to use and second the expiring timeout (in seconds).
        #SSLSessionCache         "dbm:c:/Apache24/logs/ssl_scache"
        SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:g:/wamp/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
        SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

        ##
        ## SSL Virtual Host Context
        ##

        <VirtualHost _default_:8090>

        #   General setup for the virtual host
        DocumentRoot "g:/wamp/www"
        ServerName x.x.x.x:8090
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        ErrorLog "g:/wamp/logs/error.log"
        TransferLog "g:/wamp/logs/access.log"

        #   SSL Engine Switch:
        #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
        SSLEngine on


        SSLCertificateFile "g:/wamp/OpenSSL/certs/webserver.cert"
        #SSLCertificateFile "c:/Apache24/conf/server-dsa.crt"
        #SSLCertificateFile "c:/Apache24/conf/server-ecc.crt"

        #   Server Private Key:
        #   If the key is not combined with the certificate, use this
        #   directive to point at the key file.  Keep in mind that if
        #   you've both a RSA and a DSA private key you can configure
        #   both in parallel (to also allow the use of DSA ciphers, etc.)
        #   ECC keys, when in use, can also be configured in parallel
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "g:/wamp/OpenSSL/certs/webserver.key"
        #SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/Apache24/conf/server-dsa.key"
        #SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/Apache24/conf/server-ecc.key"







        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory "c:/Apache24/cgi-bin">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>


        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
                 nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                 downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0


        CustomLog "G:/wamp/logs/ssl_request_log" \
        "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

        </VirtualHost>  
        <VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName x.x.x.x:8090
            Redirect / https://x.x.x.x:8090/
        </VirtualHost>
```

when i open https://x.x.x.x:8090
it gives the correct index fiel what i have put in wamp/www.
but if i open http://x.x.x.x.8090/ it gives the following error

```
Bad Request

    Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
    Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
    Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
    Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.12 Server at 192.168.1.90 Port 8090
```

why i am not able to redirect the http to htts even i have set the virtual host for 8090 in http-ssl.conf file. Is there an conflict between 8090 and 80 port ...

Answer (score 0):

Your port 8090 is set up to accept HTTPS. You can't hit it with an unencrypted request and expect that it'll talk back and instruct your browser to use HTTPS. Apache doesn't work that way.

I don't see a conflict between the two ports. The behaviour I would expect is that when you hit your site via HTTP on port 80, it'll redirect you to HTTPS on port 8090. That's what you'll normally do in a "real" world setup; you'd have http://example.com (on port 80) redirect to https://example.com (on port 443).

Comment: Well,.. so how can i make the redirection from http to https in my case

Comment: You'll need mod_rewrite in apache; using the directives: `RewiteEngine on` / `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` / `RewriteRule  ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}:8090/$1 [R,L]`. This goes into the plain-HTTP virtual host (at port 80).